# Using the Continuation character in a DEFINE statement in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following code in which I'm using a variable to pass a list of values to multiple SQL statements (I can't save in a table as I don't have authority and don't want to have to maintain the list in all of the various SQL sections).

It works fine as long as all of the values are on a single line... but as I have so many values; I'd like to split it into multiple lines and use the Continuation Character '-'.

I'm running `Oracle SQL Developer 2.1.1.64` against `Oracle 10g` (I also tried this in `PL/SQL Developer` and it failed there as well)

```
--=========================================

   define subclasses = ('10-1010-10','10-1010-15','10-1010-20', -

    '10-1010-25','10-1010-30')   --- there are another 60 values...


    select item from item_master where ((subclass) in &&subclasses);

    Select Price from Item_prices where ((subclass) in &&subclasses);

--=========================================
```

I get the following error

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
```

as it is parsing the code as

```
select item from item_master where ((subclass) in ('10-1010-10','10-1010-15',
'10-1010-20', -'10-1010-25','10-1010-30'))
```

...keeping the continuation code '-' in the SQL....tho it DOES go to the 2nd line of values.

If I remove the '-' ...  it only processes the values on the first line and parses as

```
select item from item_master where ((subclass) in ('10-1010-10','10-1010-15','10-1010-20', )
```

... losing the second to nth line of values (and throwing errors as it ends w/ ',' and doesn't have the final ')'). How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
column subc new_value subclasses

select q'[('10-1010-10','10-1010-15','10-1010-20',
'10-1010-25','10-1010-30')]' as subc
from dual;
```

Now `&subclasses.` will contain all the codes.

NB I used the q'[...]' quote syntax to avoid have to double up all the quotes in the data.

Comment: Adding `noprint` to the `column` line will stop the string being printed out, which might make it a little more pleasant; and `set verify off` might be useful to hide the substitutions if you aren't already doing that. (For the OP's benefit, obviously, I'm pretty sure Tony knows this... *8-)

Comment: Thanks - just tried the following...

column subc new_value subclasses select q'[('10-1010-10','10-1010-15','10-1010-20','10-1010-25','10-1010-30', '10-1010-35','10-1010-40','10-1010-45','10-1015-10','10-1015-15','10-1015-20', '10-1015-25','10-1015-30','10-1015-35','10-1015-40','10-1015-45','10-1020-10', '10-1020-15','10-1020-20','10-1020-25','10-1020-30','10-1020-35','10-1020-40', '10-1020-45','10-1020-50','10-1020-55','10-1020-60','10-1020-65')]' as subc from dual; 

select item from item_master where ( subclass in &&subclasses );

Comment: but it's still prompting for SUBCLASSES:

The parsed SQL shows 

Select item from item_master where (subclass in null)

so it didn't pull in the &&Subclasses values at all

THANKS

Comment: NOTE - the SUBC value run in the Select from Dual part does LOOK ok.... it just isn't making it into the Subclasses Variable as it should

Comment: I can't see anything wrong - in fact I just copied and pasted your code into SQL Developer (Version 4.0.0.12) and it ran OK without prompting.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try updating my Sql Developer as I'm running Oracle Sql Developer 2.1.1.64 against Oracle 10g

Comment: Thanks - I upgraded to 4.0.1.14 and was NOT able to get it to run... 

the final query which was using the &&Subclasses variable STILL popped up looking for user input rather than using the Column New_Value assignment 

anyway - I WAS ABLE to get the line continuation character to work as it should 

I used a double -   

Define Subclasses = ('10-1010-10','10-1010-15', --
  '10-1010-20','10-1010-25')

YEA!!

THANKS for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are trying to substitute a list of string variables into the select statement. You should rewrite your define statement to make it a single list of strings like this:

```
define subclasses = '''10-1010-10'',''10-1010-15'',''10-1010-20'', -
    ''10-1010-25'',''10-1010-30''';   --- there are another 60 values...
```

The `-` should be fine as a continuation character (see [Oracle documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12017.htm)).

Now, when you execute your select statements you need to edit the WHERE clause so they are formatted so it will plug those values directly in there as written:

```
    Select item from item_master where subclass in (&subclasses);

    Select Price from Item_prices where subclass in (&subclasses);
```

This will end up being interpreted as if you had written:

```
Select item from item_master 
where subclass in ('10-1010-10','10-1010-15','10-1010-20', '10-1010-25','10-1010-30');
```

If you have a lot of values though, you might run into [limitations for substitution variables](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables#6_4) if you are using SQL*Plus (i.e. limited to 240 bytes per variable). In that case, you can either split the variables into multiple variables and concatenate them in the SELECT, or if you are in a PL/SQL environment, you can create variables that will hold the larger data size.